# Processus stochastiques et mouvement brownien by Paul Lévy

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

Does anybody know if there is an English or German translation of the book *Processus stochastiques et mouvement brownien* by Paul Lévy?

If not, can someone recommend a text covering similar contents but in English or in German?

Comment: Are you sure it exists? Searching MathSciNet and ZBMath gives, aside from the French original, only a [Russian translation](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:0248.60004&format=complete).

Comment: I'm not sure. I just hoped someone knows this book, or a book almost similar to this one.

Comment: I've edited your question in view of your recent comment.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if an English translation of Paul Levy's book doesn't exist yet. I've been searching for an English translation of his paper on Local Time, "Sur certains processus stochastiques homogenes", for nearly a year now, to no avail. (Now I'm translating it myself with the help of Google Translate and a French buddy). From what I've read about Paul Levy, many mathematicians back then didn't consider him a "real mathematician" (probably because Probability was in its infancy, so it wasn't accepted as a legitimate field of math yet).

Comment: As a result, his work seems to have been largely underrated.

Comment: There's also an article, whose French title is:
"Sur certains processus stochastiques homogènes"

But, I am also looking for an English translation.

Answer (score 4):

That is true that in France at that time, Paul Lévy was not well-known, while abroad, for example, in Russia and In U.S. he was considered as one of the founding fathers, together with A.N. Kolmogorov, of modern probability.  Then considering this situation, Parisian mathematician invited M. Loève, one of Lévy's student, to come back to Paris to sow some seed there.   Now it is well known that Lévy is the mathematician who set the tone for Modern Probability while Kolmogorov set the axiomatic measuretical model for probability.

There is no English translation of his book on stochastic process and BM. You can refer to Doob's stochastic processes or Ito and McKean's Diffusion processes and their sample paths.

OR Karatzas & Shreve's BM and Stochastic calculus. OR  Revuz et Yor's Continuous martingales and BM. I think these book could satisfy you. While Marc Yor has published a new book on Local time so that it may be helpful to you.